# MYSQL: Update table with the order in the team

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need help with MYSQL. I have a table that will have all the race finish position of every members in multiple teams. I want to be able to update a column, that would tell me what is the position of the team member in their team. It could be just SQL or a stored proc if required. I am using phpmyadmin.

So let's assume the following data (exemple). In the full table, I have about 200 riders in 20 teams but for the exemple, I will only put a few.

```
| Team ID | MemberID | Position | PositionInTeam |
| --------| -------  |----------|----------------|
| 111     | 123123   | 12       |                |
| 112     | 456456   | 51       |                |
| 113     | 789789   | 44       |                |
| 112     | 321321   | 42       |                |
| 111     | 654654   | 68       |                |
| 113     | 987987   | 14       |                |
| 112     | 741741   | 28       |                |
```

I want to run a script that would update the table to show the position of the rider inside their team (fill last column)

```
| Team ID | MemberID | Position | PositionInTeam |
| --------| ---------|----------|----------------|
| 111     | 123123   | 12       | 1              |
| 112     | 456456   | 51       | 3              |
| 113     | 789789   | 44       | 2              |
| 112     | 321321   | 42       | 2              |
| 111     | 654654   | 68       | 2              |
| 113     | 987987   | 14       | 1              |
| 112     | 741741   | 28       | 1              |
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to calculate the position of each member inside each team and join to the table:

```
UPDATE tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TeamID ORDER BY Position) rn
  FROM tablename
) tt ON tt.TeamID = t.TeamID AND tt.MemberID = t.MemberID
SET t.PositionInTeam = tt.rn
```

For prior versions, use a self join:

```
UPDATE tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t1.TeamID, t1.MemberID, COUNT(*) rn
  FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t2.TeamID = t1.TeamID AND t2.Position <= t1.Position
  GROUP BY t1.TeamID, t1.MemberID
) tt ON tt.TeamID = t.TeamID AND tt.MemberID = t.MemberID
SET t.PositionInTeam = tt.rn
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e513f872b292224cb7c280889cacfcb8).

Comment: I have Mysql10 so I used the first solution and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: @StevenSicard the latest version of MySql is 8.0.24. Maybe you are using MariaDB? In any case if this worked don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.